# How to make back button on WebView work in onBackPressed?

Tags: android

I have some list items in drawer, one upon clicked opens `WebView`. In my `MainActivity`, I define `WebView`:

```
private WebView mWebView;
```

and in `onCreate()`:

```
mWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
```

Once that drawer item is clicked, I open `WebView` like this:

```
setContentView(mWebView);
mWebView.loadUrl(...);
```

The above code successfully opens the URL in `WebView`. To go back from `WebView`, I tried the below code in `onBackPressed()`:

```
if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
    mWebView.goBack();
}
```

But nothing happens. I also have other code in `onBackPressed()` which I tried to put in the `else` block but whenever I press back, the code in the `else` bloc triggers, the `if` part never does. So it looks like `mWebView` in `onBackPressed()` is not getting recognized. How to make it work?

Comment: Maybe you HTML is not really navigating, but just updating the URL (e.g. it is a SPA Single Page Application, and is modifying the hash part). Is it a React, Vue.js, Angular or something similar? I would try to open the URL in your computer using a regular browser, to see if back button works here.

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana It's a simple html page.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood you. You're calling `setContentView(mWebView);` in reaction to the drawer menu option clicked, right? This means you're replacing your view hierarchy. That's not the way it should be done. `mWebView.goBack()` is to navigate back inside the `WebView`. You should open another `Activity` in reaction to the drawer menu option selected, or use `Fragments`.

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana Thanks, now I know `goBack` is only for navigating within WebView. To make the current code work, what I did is check if webview is not null in `onBackPressed` and `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` and called all the other methods in `onCreate`. Basically called everything which was already present in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 2):

Here how my web view navigation works.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);

        setContentView(webView);
        webView.loadUrl(...);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView != null && webView.canGoBack()) {
           webView.goBack();
        }
    }

}
```

You need to add your back handler inside `onBackPressed()` 
I hope this will help you.